# How to Sum using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm attempting to Sum the cost of all the parts int a group.

My Total, TotalLength, Loss, and CutPart work as expected.

When I Sum the cost for all the parts in the group I'm not getting the expected results.

Everything calculates perfectly but not the Sum / Cost

--Here is where I'm grouping

```
 List<PartsProcessor.IPart> parts = Task.Run(async () => await this.ProcessedParts.CombineParts(false)).Result;

//Stocks
this.StockLengths = parts.GroupBy(o => new { o.PartNumber, o.StockLength }).Select(g => new PartsProcessor.GroupedPart
{
    Total = (g.Key.StockLength > 0 ? int.Parse((Math.Ceiling(g.Sum(s => s.Length) / (g.Key.StockLength))).ToString()) : 1),
    TotalLength = g.Sum(s => s.Length),
    Loss = g.Key.StockLength > 0 ? (g.Key.StockLength * (Math.Ceiling(g.Sum(s => s.Length) / (g.Key.StockLength)))) - (g.Sum(s => s.Length)) : 0,
    **Cost = g.Sum(s => s.Cost),**
    CutPart = g.FirstOrDefault()
}
                                     )
.Where(w => w.CutPart.Category.ToLower() != "glass" &&
            w.CutPart.Category.ToLower() != "glazing" &&
           !w.CutPart.Category.ToLower().Contains("epdm") &&
           !w.CutPart.Category.ToLower().Contains("end dam") &&
            w.CutPart.Category.ToLower() != "leaf" &&
            w.CutPart.Category.ToLower() != "door frame").ToList<PartsProcessor.IGroupedPart>();
```

--Properties in debug mode

In the two snap shots below it shows the Cost for each, Total parts needed, and the total Cost. But the total cost is not correct.

Where am I going wrong here?

[image: Snap 1]

[image: Snap 2]

[image: Snap 3, 1 and 2 combined]

Comment: If it were me I wouldn't use the ternary operator. Not sure if it matters for your issue, but there's too much going on multiple parens etc.. Imho for ?: usage.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but it looks like the group by/select is done first, and that is where the sum is.  THEN you do the where to limit the values.  Try doing the where first, then the group by/select.

Comment: The values look reasonable. Why are they incorrect? Give us data that allows us to diagnose the issue. Right now you can only hope that someone luckly spots the issue (I didn't - it is a simple Sum call after all!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Responsding to your request from the comments I provide the following snippet:

```
from w in parts
where Filter(w)
group w by new { w.PartNumber, w.StockLength } into g
let someValue = int.Parse((Math.Ceiling(g.Sum(s => s.Length)/(g.Key.StockLength))).ToString())
select new
{
    Total = g.Key.StockLength > 0 ? someValue : 1,
    TotalLength = g.Sum(s => s.Length),
    Loss = g.Key.StockLength > 0 ? someValue - (g.Sum(s => s.Length)) : 0,
    Cost = (g.Key.StockLength > 0 ? someValue : 1)*g.Average(s => s.Cost),
    CutPart = g.FirstOrDefault(),
};
```

You can reuse `someValue` as often as you want.

Comment: Ok, I see how you did that with the group, that is where I was getting lost. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with the code below. Moving the where and groupby didn't help. Since the average is always going to be the same I was able to write the code like I have below.

```
 this.StockLengths = parts
                     .Where(w => w.Category.ToLower() != "glass" &&
                            w.Category.ToLower() != "glazing" &&
                           !w.Category.ToLower().Contains("epdm") &&
                           !w.Category.ToLower().Contains("end dam") &&
                            w.Category.ToLower() != "leaf" &&
                            w.Category.ToLower() != "door frame")

                    .GroupBy(o => new { o.PartNumber, o.StockLength }).Select(g => new PartsProcessor.GroupedPart
                {
                    Total = (g.Key.StockLength > 0 ? int.Parse((Math.Ceiling(g.Sum(s => s.Length) / (g.Key.StockLength))).ToString()) : 1),
                    TotalLength = g.Sum(s => s.Length),
                    Loss = g.Key.StockLength > 0 ? (g.Key.StockLength * (Math.Ceiling(g.Sum(s => s.Length) / (g.Key.StockLength)))) - (g.Sum(s => s.Length)) : 0,
                    Cost = (g.Key.StockLength > 0 ? int.Parse((Math.Ceiling(g.Sum(s => s.Length) / (g.Key.StockLength))).ToString()) : 1) * g.Average(s => s.Cost),
                    CutPart = g.FirstOrDefault()
                }
                  ).ToList<PartsProcessor.IGroupedPart>();
```

Comment: Just a tip - use query expressions and pull the duplicated calculations into a `let`. Also, get rid of the string parsing. Use `(int)myDouble` instead.

Comment: `from w in parts where Filter(w) group w by new { w.PartNumber, w.StockLength } let someIllegibleValue = int.Parse((Math.Ceiling(g.Sum(s => s.Length) / (g.Key.StockLength))).ToString()) select new { /* use g and someIllegibleValue  here */}`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to alter the answer code and set that let value? Or post an answer code with the let value set by using the answer code I posted? Specifically setting a total let value.